# How to make Comma enterable into EditText only once?

Tags: java, android

I have been working on something for quite a while now, but I just cant get it done. My problem is that I have a EditText where I want the User to be able to input a decimal number (for example 3,95 or 3.95). I put the inputType to numberDecimal and also tried limiting the digits to "0123456789,." but it either didnt let the User input a comma or it let the user input loads of them. I want the user to be able to input only one seperator (whether its "." or ","). Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: _I have been working on **something** for quite a while now, but I just cant get it done_ [...] No code provided. StackOverflow in a nutshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check format in realtime.

```
1. replace , => .
2. cast to double
if casting fails, go back to backuped string.
```

At layout xml :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789.,"/>
```

At java

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            String sBackup;

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                double value;
                try {
                    if (editable.toString().equals("") == false) {
                        value = Double.valueOf(editable.toString().replace(',', '.'));
                        sBackup = editable.toString();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    editText.setText(sBackup);
                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

First get seperator based on locale.

```
DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) 
DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols=format.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
defaultSeperator=Character.toString(symbols.getDecimalSeparator());
```

Then, set textwatcher for restriction.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
if(editable.toString().contains(defaultSeperator))
    editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
else
    editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789" + defaultSeperator));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an Input Filter on Edit text.

```
 public static InputFilter getFilter() {
    return new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int index = start; index < end; index++) {
               // Filter here
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}



et_Txt.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{getFilter()});
```

Then Validate each character input as per your Requirement.